# Crash app with CocoaPods on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I added pods to my application and it started crashing on some devices. I made holloworld project with the same result. This is the my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
#pod 'SHOmniAuth',    :git => "http://github.com/seivan/SHOmniAuth", :branch => :develop
pod 'SHOmniAuthFacebook'
pod 'SHActionSheetBlocks'
pod 'SHAlertViewBlocks'
pod 'SHFastEnumerationProtocols'
pod 'authorizenet-sdk'
```

I made 'pod install', 'pod update'. Can somebody tell me where is a problem? If I install ad hoc on my mac everything is ok. If I install on other PC I have crash.

Comment: What is the type of crash, where it happends? May be it is not cocoapods fault?

Comment: i tried on hello world app without any call. Crash on start app. Immediately after default screen.